# Firebase query silently fails on iOS after upgrading to 4.1.0

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a query:

```
let uri = UriConstants.getPaymentMethodsUri(userId: uid)
NSLog("Setup payment methods: \(uri)")
let reference = Database.database().reference(withPath: uri).queryOrdered(byChild: "o")
reference.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snap in
    NSLog("This does not get called ever with 4.1.0")
})
```

and with 4.0.4 dependency of Firebase it works correctly, but with 4.1.0 or newer it silently fails. (Or never excutes, not sure what happens.) The symptom is that the NSLog line is never called.

The `pod update` lists the following as updated:

```
Installing Firebase 4.1.0 (was 4.0.4)
Installing FirebaseAnalytics 4.0.3 (was 4.0.2)
Installing FirebaseAuth 4.1.0 (was 4.0.0)
Installing FirebaseCore 4.0.5 (was 4.0.4)
Installing FirebaseDatabase 4.0.1 (was 4.0.0)
Installing FirebaseInstanceID 2.0.2 (was 2.0.0)
Installing FirebaseStorage 2.0.1 (was 2.0.0)
Installing leveldb-library (1.18.3)
```

I tried to see the release notes and what not, but I am really at loss how to diagnose this. There is data, the user executing the query has correct rights and there are no exceptions or errors.

This is my AppDelegate:

```
override init() {
  FirebaseApp.configure()
  Database.database().isPersistenceEnabled = true
  Database.setLoggingEnabled(true)
}
```

Comment: Why arent you using `print` instead of `NSLog` ?

Comment: Would that change something? What's the value of your comment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For reasons unknown to me, neither 4.1.0 or 4.1.1 works, but now that 4.2.0 is published, it seems to work ok. Thus closing this as there is no point trying to hunt down the reason anymore.